# Android OnLocationChanged invalid GPS position

Tags: android, gps

Sometimes I receive an invalid/wrong position from GPS. I´m not talking about meters but several kilometers. Sometimes more then 300Km. I searched a lot and still not found a solution.

Here is one example of tonight:

09-13 21:33:29.788 V/TEST﹕ onLocationChanged GPS 21:33:28 13/09/2014, XX.603674, XX.154188, 20.0
09-13 21:33:31.338 V/TEST﹕ onLocationChanged GPS 21:33:30 13/09/2014, XX.603633, XX.154111, 20.0
**09-13 21:35:24.061 V/TEST﹕ onLocationChanged GPS 21:35:25 13/09/2014, XX.567266, XX.031885, 10.0**
09-13 21:36:16.226 V/TEST﹕ onLocationChanged GPS 21:36:17 13/09/2014, XX.603408, XX.153793, 20.0

Not so far, about 12km this time. But some times is very, very far away. My device is a Samsung GT-I9100 (4.1.2).

This is the code (I´m not testing for location.hasAccuracy because there´s no diference in this case):

```
        LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (location == null) return;
            Log.v(TAG, "onLocationChanged GPS " + getCurrentTime(location.getTime(), false) + ", " +
                    String.format("%.6f", location.getLatitude()) + ", " + String.format("%.6f", location.getLongitude()) + ", " + String.format("%.1f", location.getAccuracy()));

        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30, 5, gpsLocationListener);
```

Am I doing something wrong????

Comment: How frequently do these incorrect values appear? GPS has been known to occasionally return incorrect values from time to time. (Though being several hundred km is highly suspect)

Comment: You have to be outdoor for GPS to work properly. If you're going to test GPS functionality, do it with a laptop and test GPS outdoor.

Comment: yes i agree, it sometimes is erradic and i can see it bounce from place to place sometimes but I assume it's because it's locking in on my gps, and uses wifi/cell towers and then if gps is available.

Comment: I don´t care with wrong positions. But I need to know how wrong it is.

Comment: Erad, appear always at night and indoor. This is my worst case GPS constellation scenario. I know I can get wrong positions in this cases. The question is: How to know if it is a wrong position if accuracy is 10, 20 or 30 meters and location is 300km far away? I´m developing a tracking application and I can not show to my client a position 300Km wrong and say the accuracy/error is 20 meters!